# QGIS - creating VRT does nothing

Tags: qgis, vrt

I've got 69 .asc files to make a nice colored and shadowed elevation map or levels contours, and maybe a 3D view.
They all open and get shadows. One by one…

So I would like to create a VRT ("menu:raster:miscellaneous:Build virtual raster" or with toolbox:GDAL. When I open the window to select my files and hit "ok", both VRT window and select box close and it does nothing.
When I try to merge several .asc file I get the same result.

What went wrong? are .asc not suitable for VRT? A Python crash? A badly configured QGIS?

Or just out of memory? (each asc file has 1 million points, it made a lot, but with just 4 tiles it does the same "nothing")

MacOS High Sierra (10.13), QGIS 3.10 Coruña, GRASS 7.8, GDAL/OGR 2.4.1, Python 2.7

The installation of GRASS was tricky (config of path to GRASS)
When I  try to create contour, it runs but log says that the result layer was not correctly generated.

Comment: ASCII has got to be the least efficient format available, so that's probably your first hurdle.

Comment: You mean the best is to convert asc files to images grid and then build a VRT ?

Answer (score 1):

When the OK button is pressed in the Built Virtual Raster tool after the files have been selected a new tab "Parameters" should open. At this state nothing has  really happened yet. The tool has built a list of the selected files and a template GDAL command has been created. No checking if the selected files are valid is done. I verified that by selecting one .txt file into the mosaic  and the Parameters tab was still opened.

[image]

That you have asc files has nothing to do with your issue. I suppose that there is generally something wrong with your QGIS installation.

Comment: The tab "Build Raster Tool" close at the same time the "ok" button of the "select file" window is hit.  You are probably right about something wrong with QGIS installation. But what ? Can't figure what for 3 days…

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the log & message, it seems that the problem came from Python:

> warning:/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py:737:
> DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of
> importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)